# soapUI Xpath junit fails when try Property Transfer

Tags: xpath, junit, soapui

i've imported saxon xbean and xbean_path  i still don't know what is wrong.
i'm trying soapUI project running with junit

```
Property Transfer
    Error:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.PropertyTransferException:  Trying XBeans path engine... Trying XQRL... Trying delegated path engine... FAILED on 
    declare namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I made it work my problem was the version of saxon i was importing so if someone have same problem just download the right version to your xbean version :D